# Prove that the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 - y^4 = 0\}$ is not a manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

I needed to prove that the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 - y^4 = 0\}$ is not a manifold.

I defined the function $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^4$ and calculated the gradient $(2x, -4y^3)$ to identify the critical point $(0, 0)$. This point is indeed in our set, therefore I concluded the set is not a manifold.

But this is apparently not enough to prove this fact. What am I missing? What else do I need to do in order to prove a set is *not* a manifold?

Comment: prove that it is not locally euclidean. It is the union of the curves $\{x-y^2=0\}$ and $\{x+y^2=0\}$. What happens if you remove $(0,0)$?

Comment: $g(x,y) = x^9 - y^3$ also has a critical point at $(0,0)$, which is in the set $\{(x,y)\mid g(x,y) = 0\}$. Yet that set is a manifold. The definition of manifold says nothing about critical points of some function, nor is there some theorem that indicates the level sets of a function which pass through critical points cannot be manifolds.